# Photoshop background cancellation/phasing removal?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Lets say I have a picture like this: [pic one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgTBu.jpg)

And an original pic: [original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nhghv.jpg)

Is it possible to remove the background by sort of cancelling the background out or phasing it out since and remain with just the text? Sort of hard to explain but I hope you understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Open both images in photoshop on two layers - the one with the text on top.
Set blending mode of top layer to difference.
This will isolate the text.
Use the Color Range selection tool to select the black pixels and then delete them